# What does mean Lower Windows and Upper Windows in Prophet

Tags: time-series, forecasting, facebook-prophet

I'm reading the "Modeling Holidays and Special Events" in Prophet Documentation: [Documentation](https://facebook.github.io/prophet/docs/seasonality,_holiday_effects,_and_regressors.html)
But I don't understand the meaning (or use) of lower_window and upper_window :
"If you wanted to include Christmas Eve in addition to Christmas you’d include lower_window=-1,upper_window=0. If you wanted to use Black Friday in addition to Thanksgiving, you’d include lower_window=0,upper_window=1. You can also include a column prior_scale to set the prior scale separately for each holiday, as described below."

when I need to use -1, 0, or 1 in this values?

For example in this case use  all of Peyton Manning’s playoff appearances:

```
# Python
playoffs = pd.DataFrame({
  'holiday': 'playoff',
  'ds': pd.to_datetime(['2008-01-13', '2009-01-03', '2010-01-16',
                        '2010-01-24', '2010-02-07', '2011-01-08',
                        '2013-01-12', '2014-01-12', '2014-01-19',
                        '2014-02-02', '2015-01-11', '2016-01-17',
                        '2016-01-24', '2016-02-07']),
  'lower_window': 0,
  'upper_window': 1,
})
superbowls = pd.DataFrame({
  'holiday': 'superbowl',
  'ds': pd.to_datetime(['2010-02-07', '2014-02-02', '2016-02-07']),
  'lower_window': 0,
  'upper_window': 1,
})
holidays = pd.concat((playoffs, superbowls))
```

why 0 and 1?